# Return of a if using empty() function in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have following IF in my code to check if array are empty,

```
if (!empty($data['id']) && (empty($data['student_no']) || empty($data['batch']) ) ) {
   print_r("inside if ");
}
```

`$data['id']`,`$data['student_no']`,`$data['batch']` are arrays.

array values are like below,

1.`$data['id']` -> `Array ( [0] => 1  [1] => [2] => )`

2.`$data['student_no']` -> `Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => )`

3.`$data['batch']` -> `Array ( [0] =>  )`

But this does not got to inside the if and print the "inside if" string.

Please tell me what is wrong ?

Comment: But the `student_no` and `batch` are not empty.

Comment: they're not empty arrays.

Comment: if you try empty($data['batch'][0]) it should return true

Comment: Empty array is array with `NO` values. Array with one empty value is not empty.

Comment: how to get inside the `if` by these results ?

Comment: change your condition to `if (true)`. That's how you would get inside the `if` with these arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot ! in if

```
!empty($data['student_no']
```

Comment: This is that rare case, when the answerer knows the task better than the OP*. (* actually not) @Nishant Nair how do you know if they have not forgotten something else? Like a condition to check whether it's a `Tuesday` today?

Comment: OP says: _check if array are empty_

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping another set of brackets in the !empty($data['id'])

```
if ((!empty($data['id'])) && (empty($data['student_no']) || empty($data['batch']) ) ) {
   print_r("inside if ");
}
```

Comment: More parentheses for the god of parentheses!

Answer (score 0):

$data['student_no'] and $data['batch'] are not empty but your condition wants one of them empty, so it does not work